# How to do an insertion of text before a multi-line regex using sed or awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Given the following input (not literally what follows, but shown with some meta notation):

```
... any content can be above the match ...
# ... optional comment above the match ...
  # ... optional comment above the match can have spaces before it ...
 "<key>": ... any content can follow ...
... any content can be below the match ...
```

where the match is `^\s*"<key>":` where the `<key>` is a placeholder for an actual string. Note that comments are matched by `^\s*#.*`.

I want to insert a string of text before the matched `<key>` and before any comments that are immediately above the matched `<key>`. There may be a variable number of comments, or none at all.

I've come up with a solution using **sed**; however, it is very ugly because it uses a `tr` hack. I'm hoping for a simpler solution using either **sed** or **awk**.

First, here's a test case:

**test.txt:**

```
{
# 1a
# 2a
"key1": true,

# 1b
# 2b
"key2": false,
}
```

Now my present solution involves **sed** and translating all newlines to a delimiter character (`$'\x01'`) to make it easier to do multi-line operations. My example involves a regex that matches multiple comment lines followed by a key-value pair.

```
# The string to insert before the match
s='# 1x
# 2x
"keyx": null,

'

# Define the key before which to do the insertion:
Key='key2'

# Normalize that string: s -> ns
ns="$(printf '%s' "$s" | tr '\n' $'\x01')"

# Normalize test.txt
tr '\n' $'\x01' < test.txt |
# Perform the multi-line insertion
sed "s/\(^\|\x01\)\(\(\s*#[^\x01]*\x01\)*\)\(\s*\"$Key\":\)/\1$ns\2\4/" |
# Return to standard form with newlines
tr $'\x01' '\n'
```

The above code when executed with the **test.txt** input produces the correct and expected output:

```
{
# 1a
# 2a
"key1": true,

# 1x
# 2x
"keyx": null,

# 1b
# 2b
"key2": false,
}
```

How might I improve on what I've done above using **sed** or **awk** to make for more maintainable code? Specifically:

- Is there another way to do this using sed without the `tr` hack above?
- Is there a simpler way to do this using awk?

Comment: @EdMorton My assumption is that this kind of thing could be done much more simply in awk. And, perhaps there is a better way to do this using sed without relying on the tr hack. I'm looking for a simpler solution. The solution I have right now works, but it is hard for others to understand.

Comment: Hi Ed... I've updated the text of the OP to "produces the correct and expected output". Your confirmation about my approach is exactly why I'm hoping to here about better ways of doing this so that I can start doing things like this better from now on. Thanks.

Comment: My first sentence is: I want to be able to insert a block of text before a multi-line regex. It could be improved to: ... insert a block of text before the match indicated by a multi-line regex. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I've tried to follow the format you mention above.

Answer (score 1):

Following your update that the input could include either no or varying amounts of comments, this is the edit (due to some problems editing it, I'm having to edit out v1, so if you want it back leave a comment.)

`sed` doesn't do loops or if/elses really, just labels and branches, so trying to pick a range of lines is a bit more complicated it seems. Or at least for my knowledge level.

```
export key='key2'
s='# 1x\n# 2x\n"keyx": null,\n'
key_pattern='[[:space:]]*"'"$key"'":'

sed -n '

/'"$key_pattern"'/ {
  :b; i\
'"$s"'
  p; d  
}

/^[[:space:]]*#/ { 
  h; :a; n; H
  /^[[:space:]]*#/ ba
  /'"$key_pattern"'/ { x; bb; }
  x; p; d; 
}

p
'
```

This script breaks into three types of patterns; where the `key_pattern` matches but is on its own (no comments before):

```
/'"$key_pattern"'/ {  # here :b creates label b, 
  :b; i\              # and inserts
'"$s"'                # the contents of this line
  p; d                # print then delete from buffer and start next line
}
```

When a group of comments is followed by the key_pattern:

```
/^[[:space:]]*#/ {   # if comment found
  h;                 # copy pattern space into hold space
  :a;                # create label a 
  n; H               # get next line, append to hold space.
  /^[[:space:]]*#/ ba              # if new line is comment, goto `a`
  /'"$key_pattern"'/ { x; bb; }    # else if our pattern retrieve hold 
                                   # and goto `b`
  x; p; d;                         # retrieve hold space, print and delete
}
```

And finally, When the line doesn't match anything else:

```
p;    # print line and start next.
```

Comment: Does the above script handle an arbitrary number of comment lines (0 or more)? The comments are optional.

Comment: @SteveAmerige I think that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code comes with these assumptions:

1. Blank line between keys and data
2. Curly braces not elsewhere

   awk '/key2/{$0 = "# 1x\n# 2x\n\"keyx\": null,\n\n"$0}ORS = RT' RS='[{}\n]\n' input_file

The main focus here is on setting up the RS value so it delimits each record